# Randomly Crop a Given Input Sequence in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want to create a function that takes in a input sequence/list of given length

`(ex: [48083, 50118, 50118, 39631, 5868, 452, 32, 460, 15, 49, 1028, 4, 252, 32, 460, 15, 49, 1028, 55, 87, 195, 722, 10, 183, 117, 912, 479, 3684, 51, 109, 16, 2788, 124, 8, 556, 8, 95, 33, 333, 732, 2923, 15, 592, 433, 4.])`

and the function will output a random seqeunce of given length say 5 from the input

`(ex: [48083, 50118, 50118, 39631, 5868] or [479, 3684, 51, 109, 16])`

It would basically look something like this -

```
def foo(x, len):
  return ...

x = [48083, 50118, 50118, 39631, 5868, 452, 32, 460, 15, 49]
output_seq = foo(x, 5) # [39631, 5868, 452, 32, 460]
output_seq = foo(x, 5) # [452, 32, 460, 15, 49]
output_seq = foo(x, 5) # [50118, 50118, 39631, 5868, 452]
```

Can this be done in python3x ? Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: With due respect I am unable to get you comment. Was my question in any part wrong ? Was this the wrong place to ask this question ?

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it currently stands, because you haven't made an honest attempt at finding a solution. All you've done is invent a dummy function `foo()`. Please read the links in my comment.

Comment: Sorry, Got it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to randomly picking a start index. You need to make sure that index gives enough room at the end to include the length you want, which will be something between `0` and the length of the list minus the size:

```
import random

l = [48083, 50118, 50118, 39631, 5868, 452, 32, 460, 15, 49, 1028, 4, 252, 32, 460, 15, 49, 1028, 55, 87, 195, 722, 10, 183, 117, 912, 479, 3684, 51, 109, 16, 2788, 124, 8, 556, 8, 95, 33, 333, 732, 2923, 15, 592, 433, 4.]

def foo(x, size):
    start = random.randint(0, len(x) - size)
    return x[start: start+size]

foo(l, 5)
# [109, 16, 2788, 124, 8]

foo(l, 5)
# [10, 183, 117, 912, 479]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `random.sample(x, len)`:

```
x = [48083, 50118, 50118, 39631, 5868, 452, 32, 460, 15, 49]
print(random.sample(x, 5))
print(random.sample(x, 5))
print(random.sample(x, 5))
```

Output:

```
[50118, 39631, 48083, 460, 452]
[452, 50118, 15, 49, 48083]
[15, 452, 48083, 50118, 39631]
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to be exactly what OP is asking for.

Comment: Nope, it's not. Read the example result sequences and Mark's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727643/1426065). They're looking to start at a random spot in the list and return the next `x` items (in this case 5).

Comment: Ah, "output a random seqeunce of given length say 5 from the input" is what OP wrote, but not what they meant...

Comment: Agreed...the question certainly could have been clearer.